# Puppeteer waitForXPath giving error: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document'

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to user puppeteer waitForXPath with an XPATH but I am getting following error

```
"Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: 
 Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '//footer//span[@data-icon="send"]' 
 is not a valid selector.
```

I have tested this XPATH in Chrome's inspect element. I don't know why puppeteer is giving me error for selector when I am using XPATH to find the element.

Line which is giving me error: `await page.waitForXPath('//footer//span[@data-icon="send"]')`

This is my puppeteer and other package versions:

`"puppeteer": "^2.1.1",
"vue": "^2.5.16",
"vue-electron": "^1.0.6",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.querySelector accepts css:

```
await page.waitFor('footer span[data-icon="send"]')
```

Comment: Yes. but I am using waitForXPath. Why is it not taking xpath as selector?

Comment: Maybe xpath is buggy? Nobody really uses it so bugs would go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

I use chained promises as below:-

`.then(page => page.waitFor(10000))
.then(() => _page)
.then(page => page.waitForXPath("//a[starts-with(./@class,'nav-link daterange') and contains(.,'Last 30 days')]"))`

It works reliably and is very readable if you know XPath